# java program to initialize 2d char array with string and then print it

Tags: java, string, multidimensional-array

`enter code here`WAP using multidimensional array to give the output as:

```
Mr. Smith
Ms. Jones
```

what i have tried is :

```
public class StringArray {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int x=2,y=10,i,j;
        String[][] myStringArray = new String[x][y];

        myStringArray[0][y]="Mr.Bisht";
        myStringArray[1][y]="Mr.Kuthrpalli";

        for(i=0;i<2;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<10;j++)
            {
                System.out.println(myStringArray[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

output: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10
         at StringArray.main(StringArray.java:12)

```
public class StringArray{
public static void main(String args[])
{
  int x=2,y=10,i,j;
  String[][] myStringArray = new String[x][y];

  myStringArray[0][y-1]="Mr.Bisht";
  myStringArray[1][y-1]="Mr.Kuthrpalli";

  for(i=0;i<2;i++)
  {
    for(j=0;j<10;j++)
    {
        System.out.println(myStringArray[i][j]);
    }
  }
}
```

}

output:

```
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
Mr.Bisht
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
Mr.Kuthrpalli
```

Comment: What is the problem with your program? What is the output? We need a little bit more details

Comment: I'm guessing it should be myStringArray[0][y-1]="Mr.Bisht";
  myStringArray[1][y-1]="Mr.Kuthrpalli";

Comment: why do you use a 2D array, and not just a 1D array? maybe you want `myStringArray[0][y]="Mr."; myStringArray[1][y]="Kuthrpalli";`?

Comment: @Lonni Besançon  , i have made those changes but 9 times null is printed too before the each names .

Comment: Please edit your question to show your code so we can help you with that. Besides, as asked by @hoijui, why do you even use a two dimensional array?

Comment: ok , actually its a module question , i posted it as it is in the module . so.it is said to use multi dimenstional  array to show names .

Answer (score 2):

```
myStringArray[0][y]="Mr.Bisht";
```

is executed with a value of y of 10 that is out of boundary.

Maximum value should be **9** because arrays are **0** based, so the range is from 0 to 9